# Crear una instancia a partir de unos parámetros pasados por teclado

Tags: java, poo, object

la duda que tengo es la siguiente: ¿podría crear una instancia a partir de unos parámetros que pasara por teclado, además de poder nombrarla yo a mi gusto? Pongo un código de ejemplo.

```
public class Personaje{
private String nombre;
private int edad;

public Personaje(String nombre, int edad){
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.edad = edad;
}

public void crearInstancia(Scanner reader){

    System.out.print("Inserte nombre");
    nombre = reader.next();

    System.out.print("Inserte edad");
    edad = reader.nextInt();

    //aqui se crearia la nueva instancia del objeto Personaje
    new Personaje(nombre, edad);
}
}
```

Una vez pasados los parámetros nombre y edad, querría introducirle un nombre para la instancia (ej. "personaje1"). ¿Podría hacerse?

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que entiendes por "nombre de la instancia"? Puedes poner un atributo "nombre" en "Personaje", pero es un atributo igual que cualquier otro.

Answer (score 2):

Una forma de conseguir lo que quieres es estableciendo un array de Personajes.
Luego, en un bucle, pides los parámetros (en este caso nombre y edad) y los vas almacenando en el array de personajes.
Ejemplo en un array de 5 personajes:

```
Personaje arrayPersonajes[] = new Personaje[5];

   for(int i = 0; i < arrayPersonajes.length; i ++) {

      System.out.print("Inserte nombre ");

      nombre = reader.next();

      System.out.print("Inserte edad ");

      edad = reader.nextInt();

      arrayPersonajes[i] = new Personaje(nombre, edad);

}
```

Y si no sabes de antemano cuántos elementos va a tener el array, puedes hacerlo con ArrayList.
Creo que es una forma de hacer lo que quieres.

Comment: No es lo que buscaba, pero es una buena opción, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

yo dejaria el codigo de la siguiente manera pero te esta ignorando el objeto porque no lo estas almacenando en ninguna parte el objeto, y es muy importante crearse siempre 2 constructores para hacer pruebas el predeterminado sin parametros

```
package ej1;

import java.util.Scanner;


    public class Personaje{
        Scanner reader=new Scanner(System.in);
    private String nombre;
    private int edad;

    public Personaje(String nombre, int edad){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public Personaje(){
    this("Sin nombre",18);
    }

        public void crearInstancia(){


            System.out.print("Inserte nombre ");
            nombre = reader.next();

            System.out.print("Inserte edad ");
            edad = reader.nextInt();

            //aqui se crearia la nueva instancia del objeto Personaje
            new Personaje(nombre, edad);
        }
        }
```

y ademas haria una clase principal con el metodo main para comprobar

```
package ej1;

public class Uso_personaje {

public static void main(String[] args) {

   Personaje persona1=new Personaje();

    persona1.crearInstancia();
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Si por supuesto que puedes hacer eso, e incluso, le puedes crear mas parámetros, atributos y constructores, puedes tener N constructores, todo depende de lo que quieras lograr. Para construir una clase, e instanciarla no es necesario que todos los parámetros sean obligatorios, te pongo como ejemplo una casa, la casa tiene materiales, entre ellos están el concreto, ladrillo, columnas, entre otros, pero esos son los que son obligatorios, para que la casa tenga una funcionalidad, el resto de materiales, como ventanas, pintura, puertas, son materiales no obligatorios, le dan un extra se funcionalidad a la casa, pero no son obligatorios. Para esto sirven los constructores, para definir que tan necesario o no son los parámetros de una clase para que exista la mínima funcionalidad.

También es recomendable crear métodos que devuelvan los atributos de esta clase, para que otras clases la pueden utilizar y modificar, en este caso solo puse que las devuelva, por lo tanto no se pueden modificar desde otras clases.

Por ultimo, un metodo `static` se carga en memoria al ejecutarse el programa, y no es necesario instanciar una clase para poderla llamar y utilizar.

Ahora, en tu ejemplo, están indicando que, para una persona es necesario un `nombre` y `edad`. Tu caso de instancia seria de la siguiente manera:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Personaje{
    private String nombre;
    private int edad;

    public Personaje(String nombre, int edad){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public String getNombre(){
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public int getEdad(){
        return this.edad;
    }

    public static Personaje crearInstancia(Scanner reader){

        System.out.println("Inserte nombre");
        String nombre = reader.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Inserte edad");
        int edad = reader.nextInt();

        //aqui se crearia la nueva instancia del objeto Personaje
        return new Personaje(nombre, edad);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Personaje p1 = Personaje.crearInstancia(new Scanner(System.in));
        System.out.println(p1.getNombre());
        System.out.println(p1.getEdad());
    }

}
```

Hay otras formas de crear este objeto, sin necesidad de que tenga que pasar por la función `crearInstancia`, de hecho, todo lo puedes hacer dentro del `main`, el programa quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Personaje{
    private String nombre;
    private int edad;

    public Personaje(String nombre, int edad){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public String getNombre(){
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public int getEdad(){
        return this.edad;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Inserte nombre");
        String nombre = reader.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Inserte edad");
        int edad = reader.nextInt();


        Personaje p1 = new Personaje(nombre, edad);

        System.out.println(p1.getNombre());
        System.out.println(p1.getEdad());
    }

}
```

Como ves, el resultado es el mismo que el anterior, solamente que en este es un poco mas eficiente, ya que no carga el método `crearInstancia` en memoria, por lo que ayuda a optimizar el espacio de este. En esta aplicación lo anterior no tiene tanta validez, pero en aplicaciones grandes se nota una diferencia.

Por ultimo, puedes crear un arreglo en el cual almacene personajes, solamente haciendo `Personaje personajes = new Personaje[10];`